# Хранение истории в БД

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, проектирование

Подскажите, как лучше хранить историю в БД?
Вот допустим есть таблица Продуктов, а эта таблица связана со всякими заказами и т п.
Спустя какое-то время предприятие больше не собирается выпускать какой-то продукт и с ним что-то нужно сделать, что бы он не отображался нигде, но данные при необходимости можно было получить(Например выручка по этому продукту, заказы и т п).

Как лучше поступать с такими записями? У меня есть идея помечать их специальным признаком IsDeleted и делать фильтрацию по нему, тогда он не будет фигурировать  и можно будет получить информацию при необходимости. На сколько правильный этот подход?

И еще такой вопрос:
Допустим продукт может иметь 1 из 5 типов.
С одной стороны я их могу перечислить в CHECK, а с другой я могу создать отдельную сущность под типы.
Какой вариант более правильный?

Comment: Мне ваша идея с пометкой то же нравится, городить копию всех таблиц ради архива и отдельная с ним работа слишком накладна. Для некоторых случаев можно и view сделать, которые будут показывать только рабочие записи. По второму вопросу, если есть хоть малейшая вероятность появления 6-го типа - делайте сущность. Никто не мешает, кстати, вместо ID использовать коды из 1-2 символов, если так вдруг понятнее выглядит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По первому вопросу. Вы на правильном пути! Создаете столбец и указываете тип boolean.

По второму - вы тоже на правильном пути! Отдельная таблица с типами товаров.
А в таблице с товарами создаете столбец, где указывается идентификатор строки с типом (id типа).

Comment: По поводу is_deleted, по секрету, во всех базах данных так и делается + хранится дата и время удаления. Правда чаще называют просто deleted и тип boolean, конечно же

Comment: Если +дата удаления, то эту самую дату и можно использовать как признак удаления